# Creating Solr Config Sets without zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

i have a very special situation, where i can not access zookper via SSH on the server i am running solr on. (Neither root nor sudo permissions). My question might be tricky or trvial, i am no expert regarding solr.

Anyways, would it be possible to create a configset (With my schema.xml and solrconfig.xml) without zookeeper? Solr is running with the cloud option. I cannot access the path where the files necesary for the config sets are. The best thing would be to completly bypass zookeeper or install solr without the necessity of zookeeper (Like, without the cloud option).

KR
L

Comment: Your question is little unclear to me. You can always use the solr in Stand alone mode, what is the issue in that?

Comment: I had the feeling that my question would be unclear. The Issue is, that i don't have much experience wiht solr. How do you start solr in standalone mode? I searched on gogle but it is quite a pain to find something ._.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr

Comment: If you don't have much Solr knowledge and a Pluralsight subscription (or trial) this might help: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/enterprise-search-using-apache-solr